# Review queue: first question and first answer silver awards

Tags: discussion

I have a distinct hunch that the 'silver badge award' statistics for **first question** and **first answer** sections of the review queue have been 'zeroed', possibily following the upgrade from Bioinformatics SE beta. I dunno, because I don't consign my review stats to memory.

For example, some of the long term senior members here have statistics of '*1 review*' in both queues and can't possibly represent their contribution over such an extended period.

Has anyone else a comparable hunch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got a better response from the moderator's forum.

There used to be a different queue category - First posts, that got split into two "First questions" and "First answers". And there has been a [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396/719061). There is also a ? mark that gives you the info about number of tasks that got carried over

[image]

So the total numbers are just after the split, while the badge numbers are carrying over credit from reviewing the original "First Post" queue. The only part I am still unsure by, is why it's contributing to my gold badge only, but I suppose that's because I got a silver badge for these review tasks already (which would suggest that reviewing tasks are actually different than upvotes - the clock does not restart with an awarded badge. I might edit this post once I have ~200 more first questions reviewed).

Comment: Thank you @KamilSJaron that all makes sense. SE have done a good job, just not told anyone about it. I agree the previous silver must have been awarded (I haven't checked mine but presume so) and then zeroed the silver count. The tally carries onto gold. I should have twigged, there were 6 review queues and there are now 7 queues.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - thanks for all the reivewing work do do!

And yeah, there is something a bit strange about that. At least the number "reviews all-time" is for sure off.

As on the following screenshot - it says there were 202 reviews of first question in all-time. Which is obviously a bs, both you and myself have more than that (we both have the silver badge for 250 review tasks). But then I am quite puzzled how can I have 27/250 progress on "Reviewer" badge as I have it already.

[image]

One thing I have noticed before with upvoting badges is that once you get the silver badge, it restarts the count for the gold badge, so to get the gold badge you need 910 vote counts, not 600. I think the same is with reviewing, so to whatever your badge progress is, you got to add 251.

You got the Reviewer badge for this category on Mar 23 2020, assuming a constant rate of queue processing you should have a few hundred review tasks done by now :-).

Would you like me to ask on the moderator forum?

Comment: Hi @KamilSJaron that would be cool, thanks. The official total number of reviews of all time for first answer is '49' ...